# Number of days between today and your birthday using LocalDate class?

Tags: java, date, calculator

I want to calculate the number of days between "today" and the user's birthday, which he/ she inputs. This is what the program should look like:

```
When are you born? 19961020 // the user inputs this
Today you are xxxx days old.
```

The date needs to be in this format: YYYYMMDD. And the program should also consider leap years. I have to use the LocalDate class:

```
 LocalDate datum = LocalDate.now();
int år = datum.getYear();
int månad = datum.getMonthValue();
int dag = datum.getDayOfMonth();
```

Another thing I have to consider while coding is that I have to use my own code, and not other methods that are already made. Can you please help me with this? I have no clue where to start or how to proceed with my code.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#until-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate- maybe? (or the other "until")

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683312/formula-to-calculate-difference-between-two-dates (for some "math" approach)

Comment: you can use `java.util.Calendar` API eg:http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-calendar.html

Comment: try this `int days = Days.daysBetween(date1, date2).getDays();`

Comment: Why must you not use ready-made libraries? That's exactly what you should do with date/time calls. Is this homework?

Comment: Yes, halfer, it is. I am not very good at coding, but I want to learn. I have  no clue where to start and I need help

Answer (score 1):

Parse the strings.

Your input string happens to be in standard ISO 8601 format. The java.time classes use that standard as their default when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values. So no need to specify your own formatting pattern; use a [pre-defined format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE).

```
LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.parse( "19961020" , DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE );
```

Get today. Usually I recommend passing a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) here for accuracy, but give or take a day does not really matter here in this scenario.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
```

Ask for days between with the [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) class.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( birthdate , today );
```

## `Period`

You could use the [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class which represents a span of time as a number of years, months, and days.

```
Period period = Period.between( birthdate , today );
```

Comment: Thanks, Basil! I will try this solution

Comment: It worked! Thank you! But the thing is, is there a way that I can get the same result without using all these classes, except the LocalDate class? I have to write the code entirely with my own code

Comment: @AdamRana You mean this is a homework assignment in a school class? You should say so in your Question.